# Python UNO Game Errors

Tags: python, list

I am creating a UNO game. I think I have a problem in class Uno, def playGame and playTurn.
I get the following errors. In def playGame, I tried to check if the deck or any hands of a player is empty. If it is then the game is over and we have a winner. In playTurn I checked if there is a playable card in a player's hand by sending the card to the function canPlay. If there is a playable card then  player plays the card and I remove the card from hand.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\yaman\OneDrive\Desktop\uno_game.py", line 150, in 
> main()
>
> File "c:\Users\yaman\OneDrive\Desktop\uno_game.py", line 147, in
> main
> my_game.playGame()
>
> File "c:\Users\yaman\OneDrive\Desktop\uno_game.py", line 92, in
> playGame
> self.lastPlayedCard=random.choice(self.hand1)
>
> File "C:\Python39\lib\random.py", line 347, in choice
> return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))] TypeError: object of type 'CollectionOfUnoCards' has no len()

Comment: `CollectionOfUnoCards` has neither `__getitem__` nor `__len__` methods for you to be able to call `random.choice` or `len`on it

Comment: I added a len method but still the program fails

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. You could write far shorter code to produce the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to calculate size of CollectionOfUnoCards and program fails. In python you should declare custom `__len__` method to invoke `len` function on custom classes.

Try to add   `__len__` to CollectionOfUnoCards like this

```
class CollectionOfUnoCards:
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cardlist)
```

Also you have errors here

- `random.choice(self.hand1)` -> `random.choice(self.hand1.cardlist)`, because you can invoke random.choice on list.
- `for card in self.hand1:` -> `for card in self.hand1.cardlist:`
- `self.hand1.remove(play)` -> `self.hand1.cardlist.remove(play)`

Comment: they also need `__getitem__` because `random.choice` will try accessing an index